# preventDefault игнорируется для CustomEvent

Tags: javascript

[На MDN в документации dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) написано:

> The return value is `false` if at least one of the event handlers which handled this event called `Event.preventDefault()`. Otherwise it returns `true`.

Ну, я и пишу:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = function() {
    var event = new CustomEvent('customevent');
    var defaultPrevented = !btn.dispatchEvent(event);
    console.log(
        defaultPrevented ? 'preventDefault вызвали' : 'preventDefault НЕ вызвали!'
    );
};

btn.addEventListener('customevent', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('Кастомное событие!');
    return false;
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Но мой Firefox (впрочем, и Chromium тоже) продолжает упорно писать «preventDefault НЕ вызвали!», хотя я его вполне вызываю.

(Если я его не вызываю, то тоже пишет «preventDefault НЕ вызвали!», если что.)

Что я делаю не так?

<sup><sup>Я уже кучу кода написал с расчётом на то, что это будет работать :(</sup></sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как указано в [спецификации](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-event-preventdefault)

> The preventDefault() method, when invoked, must set the canceled flag *if the **cancelable attribute** value is true* and the in passive listener flag is unset.

То есть, данный метод устанавливает canceled флаг, если событие *cancelable*.

По умолчанию, значение атрибута *cancelable* у события - `false`, поэтому вызов *preventDefault* не оказывает никакого влияния на поведение.

Для установки *cancelable* нужно воспользоваться вторым параметром в [конструкторе CustomEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CustomEvent/CustomEvent)

Например:

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick = function() {
  var e = new CustomEvent('customevent', {
    cancelable: true
  });
  var defaultPrevented = !btn.dispatchEvent(e);
  console.log(
    defaultPrevented ? 'preventDefault вызвали' : 'preventDefault НЕ вызвали!'
  );
};

btn.addEventListener('customevent', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log('Кастомное событие!');
  return false;
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, нужно приучать себя заглядывать в спецификацию)

Comment: @andreymal, в принципе можно было и на mdn - перейти на `preventDefault` - там написано, что событие должно быть _cancelable_

Comment: Однако в документации dispatchEvent этого не упоминается, что ввело в заблуждение. Сходил дописал, благо редактирование там есть)